# In basketball, is it legal to score directly from a throw in?

Tags: rules, basketball

In basketball, is it legal to shoot and score directly from a throw in? I have seen people do it online, but I couldn't find any official rules that describe the legality of it in a real game.

Comment: Didn't this just happen in the NBA a few days ago (and was disallowed)?  Are you asking FIBA rules, or NBA rules, or something else?

Comment: @Joe [Yes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm8CS9DVsUA). It's going to be disallowed under all rules as otherwise you'd just have guys shooting unopposed threes from "the corner" all day long.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - Unopposed?  They would have a guy no more than two feet from them and 5 feet behind the arc.  That can't be more than a 10% shot.

Comment: This is perfectly legal as long as you shoot over the backboard.  Of course these are our local rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure you looked very hard :-) From the [offical FIBA rules](http://www.fiba.com/downloads/Rules/2014/Official_Basketball_Rules_2014_Y.pdf), Rule 17.3.1:

> The player taking the throw-in shall not: [...] Cause the ball to enter the basket directly

In the [NBA rules](https://turnernbahangtime.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/2014-15-nba-rule-book.pdf), this is covered by Rule 10, Section III:

> A thrower-in shall not [...] throw the ball so that it enters the basket before touching anyone on the court